# multiple array in def

Tags: puppet, puppetmaster

I have two file

```
class hadoopfile::file {

$diskname  = [aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd,eee,']

$filename  = [02,03,04,05,06]

hadoopfile::diskcreate_def { '$diskname:','$filename:' }
#hadoopfile::diskcreate_def { $filename: }
}



 define hadoopfile::diskcreate_def (
  $diskname,$filename = $title)
  {
  physical_volume {["/dev/$diskname"]:
    ensure  => present,
  }

  file { 'opt/db/$filename':
    ensure  => directory,
  }

  mount { filemount:
    ensure  => mounted,
    name    => "opt/db/$filename",
    fstype  => 'ext4',
    options => 'defaults',
    atboot  => true,
    dump    => '1',
    pass    => '2',
    require => File["/opt/hd/db/data/$filename"]
    }
   }
```

when I compile the above I got

`Syntax error at '}'; expected '}' at /etc/hadoopfile/manifests/file.pp:15 on node`
My doubt is, can we create pass two variable in define.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the single-quote **'** from the first array definition. That should make it compile.

```
$diskname  = [aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd,eee]
```

Then, according to the documentation, it is possible to pass a list of parameters to a [class](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_classes.html#defining-classes), or a [defined type](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/learning/definedtypes.html). Use this to reference your defined type

```
hadoopfile::diskcreate_def { "${diskname}":, "${filename}": }
```

Comment: In the declaration, you would 1. need to remove the double quotes and 2. use a semicolon `;` instead of comma `,` - but I don't think this is what the OP wants, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that you are looking for a mapping `drivename` to `filename`. Mappings are not expressed by pairs of arrays - they are represented by **hashes**.

```
$disks = {
    '02' => { diskname => 'aaa', },
    '03' => { diskname => 'bbb', },
    '04' => { diskname => 'ccc', },
    '05' => { diskname => 'ddd', },
    '06' => { diskname => 'eee', },
}
```

You can translate this into resources through the `create_resources` function.

```
create_resources('hadoopfile::diskcreate_def', $disks)
```

Each key in your hash becomes a resource title, and the value hash holds the attribute/value pairs.

**General remark**: Do not name your defines in this fashion. The define name should be descriptive of what each resource represents on your systems, such as `hadoopfile::mounted_volume`.